What is the logic (if any) behind Nigel Farage's claim that the west provoked Putin to invade Ukraine?
In this interview Nigel Farage states "I think the West historically , up until a few year ago, provoked Putin stupidly. I felt the ever, ever eastward expansion of NATO and the EU was giving Putin a reason to go to war." I do not understand the logic of what he is implying here. Any rational person would not consider any steps that a country takes to defend itself from invasion as a provocation. Similar logic would conclude that putting locks and alarms on your house is a provocation to criminals breaking into your house and taking your property. Walking your children or driving them to school would count as a provocation to anyone who wanted to harm your kids.
In 2021 Putin wrote an essay called "On the Historical Unity of Russians and Ukrainians" which makes it fairly clear that he considers Ukraine to historically be part of Russia and that he intends to take it back. Clearly his expansionist ambitions towards Ukraine are nothing to do with provocation and I cannot think why Farage would think that. Farage makes the "ever eastward" expansion of NATO sound like NATO has been invading countries, when really those countries joined NATO of their own free will. Historically, the West as a whole has never invaded a neighbouring country with expansionist intent of stealing territory.
Russia's twisted logic is that any country that tries to prevent them invading is provoking them to invade. I can understand the greed and desire that drives them to take a neighbour's land by force and I understand the propaganda that they use to justify their evil intentions, but I do not understand why Farage would support their propaganda.

Definitely an opinion-based + promote/discredit a PoV question. You have Farage's reasoning right there. Maybe you don't like it; maybe you don't think joining an alliance is a good casus belli. I would not necessarily disagree, but the question is still not on-topic here under two close reasons.

@gottrolledtoomuchthisweek - Not the one who threw a milkshake at him, surely?

Does this answer your question? How could the past NATO expansions in Eastern Europe be seen as justification of the Russian invasion of Ukraine in 2022? (There are also a lot of other questions such as this on similar topics.)

That sounds like it is parroting one of the excuses that Putin gave for his invasion of Ukraine in the first place. https://afsa.org/did-nato-expansion-really-cause-putins-invasion#:~:text=The%20Issue%20of%20NATO%20Expansion,its%20own%20decision%20about%20membership.

The issue here is "spheres of influence". The current Russian Federation views many nations (including Ukraine, Belarus, Chechnya, etc.) as Russian client states: weak states within its sphere of influence, particularly those of the old USSR, that should have a dependency relationship to Russia and that serve both as economic trading partners and strategic padding against Western incursions. Ukraine in particular was viewed as Russia's access to the Black Sea and global trade routes, and as a large militarily buffer that Western forces would have to cross before reaching the Russian heartland. The Kremlin saw the election of Zelenskyy — instead of the Russia-aligned candidate they sponsored — as Western provocation because it seems to lead towards an independent, unaffiliated Ukraine. Such an Ukraine would have cost Russia significantly in both strategic and economic terms.
From the Russian perspective this is somewhat reasonable; it's quite similar to the US attitude towards Cuba in the 1960s, though the US attempt to invade Cuba (Bay of Pigs) was half-baked at best. No one wants a competitor-aligned nation sitting at one's doorstep. Farage is merely echoing this concept: that Russia sees Ukraine not as intrinsically aligned with Russian culture, but as a gateway to Russian territory that would leave the Federation exposed and vulnerable to NATO. From Putin's (deeply Cold War) perspective securing (parts of) Ukraine is essential to keep the West from holding a knife to the Kremlin's throat. Whether NATO would use an alliance with Ukraine in that way is an open question — I'm not prone to overt cynicism, but have an understanding of brutish realpolitik — but it's not something Putin would be likely to risk. From Russia's perspective, Ukraine is under the Russian sphere-of-influence, and any change to that status is threatening.

I don't think it has to be either/or. Putin would obviously prefer to be surrounded by nations that are friendly to Russia, but that does not mean that he does not also have irredentist ambitions with respect to Ukraine, or indeed Belarus—he was, after all, born in a setting in which Russia, Ukraine and Belarus were for most practical purposes a single country. I suspect he has as much difficulty with the current state of affairs as some Americans might have if Puerto Rico and Texas became independent tomorrow.

The current Russian Federation views many nations (including Ukraine, Belarus, Chechnya, etc.) as russian client states In my opinion, before answering such questions it is nice to consult a map. Chechnya was a part of russia for some time. So unfortunately it is not an independent nation, although I am pretty sure soon it will be. Russian perspective this is somewhat reasonable do not see how. Delusional thoughts of a few guys is not a valid reason to kill millions.

@SalvadorDali Before the ussr collapsed, Checheno-Ingush ASSR was a part of it as well as all other republics that formed ussr. We cannot count this time inside your "for some time", as modern russian federation is not a successor of the ussr. After the ussr collapsed, Chechen Republic of Ichkeria became independent of russian federation, and modern russian federation accepted it in 1996 (similarly to how they "accepted" Ukraine's independence). However, in 2000 they annexed it back and made it a part of themselves. So, your "for some time" is between 2000 and today, which is not much at all

I'm not sure what kind of Farage-explainer you expect here.
For starters, he's campaigning, so he's looking to attract votes of those dissatisfied with current government policy of supporting Ukraine.
Also, he considers the EU an illegitimate "empire" but, he says the UK should not apologize for the British Empire.
So, in his ID-ist mindest, nationalist empires are somewhat ok, I suppose. Thus, he's not bothered much by Putin's dreams of a nationalist empire, in Russia's neighborhood.

Also, the spat between him and e.g. Johnson is not limted to this. He's also accused BoJo of being a "green"
https://www.politico.eu/article/boris-johnson-accuses-nigel-farage-parroting-putin-lie-on-ukraine-uk/ Farage is trying to differentiate himself as much as possible for the Conservative mainstream (such as it is.)

Your argumentation points to an inconsistence in Farages stance, but it does not mean that both of the statements would not be right (EU on the same path as UK once was, that is a valid view, note that he played a key role in the Brexit, thus this view is not et all surprising from him).

@GraySheep: he seems pretty consistent to me, actually.

Yes but in this case, imho, UK nationalist attitude might be his reason to defend the once existing UK empire, the same attitude leads him to attack the EU. This his view is inconsistent for us, but consistent for him.

Money?
https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/5050/russia-ukraine-war-putin-europe-far-right-funding-conservatives/
https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2024/06/03/russia-europe-far-right-espionage/
To be honest it sounds almost too cartoonishly evil because it's a bullshit excuse that right wingers have used for years to discredit genuine protests of their politics as astroturfed, but you find more and more of these headlines, including with actual investigations and evidence:
https://www.politico.eu/article/germany-mep-maximilian-krah-alternative-for-germany-afd-russia-china-payments-spying/
And it would make some sort of sense as these far right parties are often featuring deranged lunacy so that a pro-Russia or pro-Putin agenda really doesn't stick out and if they actually gain traction with their post-fact narratives then the damage can be pretty significant. Like for example a Donald Trump casting doubt on NATO can provide Russia and China with significantly more leeway in terms of whom to annex or even to nuke without fearing a reaction if all those able to object are in disarray.
And Nigel Farage in particular has proven his value by having been one of if not the driving force behind Brexit, that is he featured that campaign headed a party for it and lied to make it happen (just to drop out when it actually happened). So if one wanted to fund a UK politician to make the UK drop out of holding Russia accountable than he would be pretty high up the list.
Now that is not to say that he is or always has been a Russian asset (or better has been on their payroll), he might as well do that out of his own volition and lack of foresight, but it's at least an option.
Now while Ted Wrigley has a point about why Putin sees things the way he does, none of that would reasonably apply to Nigel Farage on the contrary for a guy who vigorously wanted to get out of even a voluntary union, thinking in spheres of influence seems rather far fetched. But outside of what politicians say and do it's really only speculation about what their intentions are.
Edit: Also beyond being sockpuppets for Russia, these parties might also try to exploit the fact that a lot of uncertainty and irrationality hides in the fog of war and that people might just want this conflict to end and if they get a narrative of a home made problem, that they have the power to change that might give them a (false) sense of agency in the issue and thus some solace. While also being a narrative that Russia really likes because it gives them a victimhood status, justifying acts of brutal aggression and giving them a pass on their end goal. So it's win win and Russia doesn't have to completely astroturf that but might nonetheless support such useful narratives where they can.

Brief semi-answer to a very complex question:
 

In 2021 Putin wrote an essay called "On the Historical Unity of Russians and Ukrainians" which makes it fairly clear that he considers Ukraine to historically be part of Russia and that he intends to take it back. Clearly his expansionist ambitions towards Ukraine are nothing to do with provocation and I cannot think why Farage would think that.

You sure? As you can see from that Wikipedia page you linked, Putin also argued that Belarusians are one people with Russians & Ukrainians. Yet he has not invaded Belarus. Why?
I suspect you can come up with some explanations. I'll posit what looks to me like the obvious one: currently Belarus has a Russia-friendly government. As long as that remains the case, Putin will not invade, but if Belarus were to attempt to leave the CSTO and join NATO, then we will have another war.
See also this, which also explains Nigel Farage's claim.

[NATO] has since taken in all of the former Soviet Union's Warsaw Pact allies, as well as the three former Soviet Baltic republics. Mr. Gromyko says the Russians signaled repeatedly to Western counterparts that inducting Ukraine or Georgia into the alliance would be a red line. At its 2008 Bucharest Summit, NATO shelved those countries' applications, but issued a statement insisting they would eventually join ... Mr. Gromyko insists Russia has nothing to apologize for. The idea of Ukraine joining NATO is as unthinkable for Moscow as, say, Mexico joining a Chinese-led military alliance would be for Washington, he suggests.
"It’s not that we view NATO as an existential threat right now," he says. “But Russia cannot accept that a country next door would be a member of a military alliance that is hostile to Russia," he says. "We are not opposed to Ukraine being democratic. It's fine with us if a neighbor has a different political and social system. But not a member of an adversarial bloc. Security is the central issue."

(If you think Mr. Gromyko was wrong in that Mexico joining a Chinese-led military alliance would be acceptable to Washington, see this question.)
You also write:

Farage makes the "ever eastward" expansion of NATO sound like NATO has been invading countries against their will. Historically, the West as a whole has never invaded a neighbouring country with expansionist intent of stealing territory. Yes Hitler did that but that is not the normal behaviour of the West or NATO.


Does it matter if an invasion is not for "stealing territory"? It's still an invasion.*
Who says NATO has never invaded countries against their will? (See examples)
What if the invasion sets up a new country over the objections of the original country? What if it causes mass misery, chaos, and extremism?

*What if the invasion is for stealing (loaded word here because it's the one you used) the resources of that country?

There twisted logic is that any country that tries to prevent them invading is provoking them to invade.

You sure? Quotes from those articles include:

"Expanding NATO would be the most fateful error of American policy in the post cold-war era. Such a decision may be expected . . . to impel Russian foreign policy in directions decidedly not to our liking."

"Signers of the second letter predicted a dark and dire outcome to these and other aspects of NATO enlargement, saying it will draw "a new line of division in Europe between the ins and the outs of a new NATO, foster instability" and diminish the security of those left out."


If it's twisted logic, how did the predictions come true?
tl; dr: be careful what you call propaganda. For much of the world, the arguments you raise in your question is the actual propaganda, and it's bewildering why people believe it.

See this question? You mean, the question that was about Russia, Ukraine, China, and the Solomon Islands, but did not mention Mexico or the USA at all? Or if we are perhaps supposed to draw an analogy from Australia to the USA, the answer—which you accepted!—pointed out that the Solomon Islands did in fact make a defense pact with China, which up until now, at least, has not led to war.

The question has its own issues, probably enough to be closed, but the answer is hardly more objective. Comparing countries voluntarily joining NATO to NATO's wars in non-member countries like Libya? And pointing out that if Belarus had joined NATO, Putin might have invaded (undoubtedly true), but missing the fact that Ukraine is not currently part of NATO nor was part of it when Russia invaded (nor at any point previously)?

Uncritically repeating Gromkyo's claims about how Russia cannot tolerate nearby countries being part of NATO, but not interrogating why this would not apply to Estonia and Latvia? A biased question needs an objective answer, but this is not such an answer.

@Obie2.0 I'm not keen to respond in comments. If you're interested, take it to chat. (If you do, I will limit myself to one response/day.)

@Allure Lets say I warn my neighbour that if he install's a bugler alarm system, I will consider that a provocation. Later on he installs an alarm system anyway. I respond by breaking into his house and stealing his valuables and trashing it. . Does that prove I was right about it being a provocation or does it justify my invasion of his property? This is an example where the prediction comes true, but where that does not make my threat or response any less twisted. Also, I meant the countries joined NATO of their own free will. Not that they were invaded.

@KDP as with Obie2.0, I'm not keen to respond in comments. If you're interested, take it to chat (feel free to ping me if you do).

Invasion can per definitionem happen only against the will of a country, otherways it would be cooperation, or alliance or anything, but not invasion.
